# QGIS adding additional (excess) map detail

Tags: qgis, layouts, qgis-print-layouts

I'm having a problem with QGIS (3.2.3-Bonn) which I hope the collective wisdom here can help with.

I'm currently trying to make a base map with GPS data on top. So far so good. I found a decent basemap, put it at the scale I wanted (which only had the big cities on and other major features). and added in some locations. However, when I export it, all of the map details are exported - including every single place name and other minor details on the map. 
I really don't want to have all of these places on, I just want what I see in the Print Layout to be what gets converted to an image but have no idea how to do this.

To highlight this I've attached a figure, on the left is a print screen of the Print Layout (and is exactly what I want to export). On the right is the same image when I export it with all the place names annoyingly added and all text now shrunk.

[image: Left - image as it appears in Print Layout. Right - image when exported as image]

Comment: A look at this question should explain : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286167/qgis-gives-different-resolution-basemap-in-print-layout

Comment: Your basemap is from a web service (it might be WMS, XYZ tile, WFS, etc, but the same principle applies). Web services are optimized for viewing on a computer screen, not for printing. Printing requires a higher resolution image, so when you print them give you a map intended for a higher zoom level (and therefore with too much detail for the print size).The link JR posted will show you how to do a workaround, to force the web service to give you the low-res image you're viewing on your screen.