# Lock the zoom level of WMS feeds when printing a layout in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3

This is similar to the following question which was asked [1 years](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286167/qgis-gives-different-resolution-basemap-in-print-layout) ago and one asked [5 years ago](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98301/how-to-print-a-wms-map-with-chosen-scale-and-wms-zoom-level/).

Is there now a way to lock the zoom level of a WMS feed in a layout? It's not an XYZ layer so I can't use the strategy mentioned in the above posts.

I want it to show as below

[image]

But it always prints at a different scale level.

[image]

I have the following settings in the print to pdf setting

[image]

Comment: what sort of WMS are you using?

Comment: The reason is that your screen has much lower resolution (DPI) than the printout. Some WMS servers support an extra parameter, like &DPI= in QGIS server https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/ogc_server_support.html

Comment: @IanTurton the WMS is https://gisservices.information.qld.gov.au/arcgis/services/Imagery/QldBase_AllUsers/MapServer/WmsServer?

Comment: As @user30184 says some WMS can allow for changes in DPI, I don't think arcgis is one of those though